ASP.NET Core Web API : CORS issue
I need your help with this one. I've looked round the internet and can't work out what I'm doing wrong.....CORS....it's a pain!
In my Program.cs, I have the following:
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
   options.AddDefaultPolicy(policy =>
   {
       policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200", "https://dev-backoffice.mydomain.com", "https://backoffice.mydomain.com")
           .AllowAnyHeader()
           .AllowCredentials()
           .AllowAnyMethod();
   });
});

and
app.UseCors(); 
app.UseStaticFiles();

But I still get a CORS error:

Access to fetch at 'https://dev-api.mydomain.com/v1/authenticate' from origin 'https://dev-backoffice.mydomain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled

Any ideas out there? I thought with what I put I more or less opened up everything as long as it came from one of the urls I gave.

Could you please help confirm whether the authentication is handled by your own application? If so, what is the authentication mechanism? I noticed the url in error message is /v1/authenticate and the error is Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check. For windows authentication, it doesn't allow annoymous option requestion which the perflight is an option request, so that for windows authentication, we need to allow annoymous requestion for testing purpose.

A CORS preflight request is used to determine whether the resource being requested is set to be shared across origins by the server. The CORS preflight uses the HTTP OPTIONS method with the ACCESS-CONTROL-REQUEST-METHOD and the ORIGIN request headers. -->https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference#cors-preflight-request

You must de defined custom policy like below and policy apply on CORS.
Step 1:
// Define the CORS policy
var CustOrigins = "_custOrigins";
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
     options.AddPolicy(name: CustOrigins,
                      policy => 
                      {
                          policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200", 
                               "https://dev-backoffice.mydomain.com",
                               "https://backoffice.mydomain.com")
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .AllowCredentials();
                      });
 });

Step 2:
// Apply the CORS policy
app.UseCors(CustOrigins);

Step 3:
Apply Cors on Controller level on Action method
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[EnableCors("CustOrigins")] // Apply CORS policy to the entire controller
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(new { Message = "CORS is applied to this controller!" });
    }
}

